# &amp; is not encoded to & using tomcat 7.0.47

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc, urlencode, spring-roo

The problem is that with some tomcat server the link tags who are & in the href value is translated to & when the page is shown but with other tomcat 7.0.47 is not and It looks very strange because it should work.

I use this:

```
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
<jsp:directive.page pageEncoding="UTF-8"/>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
</head>
```

But it continues without work fot his tomcat version.

I am using spring-mvc and the project was configured using spring-roo.

The problem happen in this custom tag.

```
 <menu:item id="fi_user_username" messageCode="global_menu_find"
                       url="/movies?find=ByMoviename&amp;form"
                       z="Pt1/VjKgu7t6Aha3OJt4uC0yZR4="/>
```

Inside the custom tag url is the ${url}.

```
            <spring:url value="${url}" var="menu_item_url"/>
            <a href="${menu_item_url}" title="${fn:escapeXml(label)}" id="${fn:escapeXml(id)}_a">
            <c:out value="${label}"/>
```

The web that is given to the browser appears the element like this:

```
<a id="fi_movie_moviename_a" title="Find by Moviename" href="/movie-server/movies?find=ByMoviename&amp;form" class="selected_movie_submenu">Find by Movie name</a>
```

Tomcat has the configuration for default.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: I'm not into JAVA world, but this has nothing to do with page encoding or even, AFAIK, to your webserver. Isn't there something like `HtmlEncode()` method in JSP ?

Comment: You aren't giving us enough information. How do you display the link tag? What element are you using to display it? How does it actually show up? It has nothing to do with IE compatibility nor JSP nor UTF-8.

Comment: The matter is that for tomcat 7.0.47 doesn't works and for Tomcat/7.0.39 it does, I think is something about tomcat configuration but when I check they are almost the same except in some mimetype tags in the server.xml file

Comment: Why don't you show us at least the code where you have such an ampersand in your JSP? You're telling us that "it" works in some version and that "it" doesn't in some other version, but we don't know what "it" actually is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem after upgrading from 7.0.42 to 7.0.47. It looks like both "Tomcat" and the Spring tag are escaping `&`.

To prevent Spring from escaping the URL, you can add `htmlEscape="false"` to the `url` tag.

Comment: That worked. I added htmlEscape="false" in my custom tag item.tagx and this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Also had this problem and was using the `htmlEscape="false"` work around mentioned above. It appears to be fixed in Tomcat 7.0.50, although I don't see it mentioned in the change log:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html

However it's possible that I missed it.